# How to select a UITextField without showing UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am wondering if there is a way to use a `UITextField` programatically (i.e.  use buttons as inputs) so that you can select a `UITextField` but not show the `UIKeyboard`, then when you select a `UIButton` it would assign a string value to the currently selected `UITextField`.

I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Maybe UITextField is not needed , you can use UILabel instead.

Comment: I am also woundering this now. I think I might go with a UILabel now and just use the highlight idea from below. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can visually change the appearance of the text field (for example add a blue border), let the user feel it’s “selected”. Then you just modify textfield.text when user presses button.

Or alternately, you can create a customized keyboard. There are many similar questions.

Comment: yea, thats what I have planned however I dont know how to hide the keyboard so that I can let the user select a UIButton that would then add the value to the UITextField previously selected.

Comment: Maybe in your case you can use UILabel instead, since you don't need you input text via keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't really need a text field (e.g., edit/select text, etc.), but a "button that stays highlighted" instead. Then, you can programmatically change the button's title label to the specified string when the user taps the 'proper' buttons.